# img inside div with padding

Tags: html, css, image, padding

I'm trying to wrap a div around an image. The image is larger than the div size. by using `Overflow: hidden` I have hidden the part of image outside the div. Now I want to set padding for my div, so the image doesn't fill all the div area. But it seems like the `img` ignores the bottom-right padding values.

To be more clear, here's what I have now (http://jsfiddle.net/sAYEq/4/):
[image]

And here's what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Please note that I do not want to set my image's width/height since I want the image to be in its actual size and the parts outside the div should not be displayed.

Comment: The problem is the width of the `wrapper` div. If you do not want to set the height/width for the image, you should not set the height/width for the div that is enclosing the image.

Comment: i see your question and enjoy from format of it.do you want to earn Custodian badges (Completed at least one review task. This badge is awarded once per review type),so look at your name in top of your page,and just click review.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply give your wrapper `100%` width and height:

```
#wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

It will work [as you want it to](http://jsfiddle.net/sAYEq/7/).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
.parent {
  width: 400px; 
  height: 200px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 10px solid white;
}
```