# Responsive image inside a div with padding

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

We have an `#inner` with `padding-top` and `padding-bottom`. The content inside the div is centered. We have an image to with `max-width:100%` and `max-height:100%`.

The image is responsive but it gets the height of the #inner with padding, and it's not centered.

CSS

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner {
    height:100px;
    padding:15px 0;
    background:yellow;
}

#container {
    height: inherit;
}

a {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="inner">
    <div id="container">
        <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried to add padding to the `<a>` tag, add an other container around the `<a>` but the image became smaller. The image should be the height of the `#inner` - 30px (padding).

I understand the problem is with the `inherit` property, but I don't know the solution.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/b8o2t31e/

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334028/img-inside-div-with-padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/71y96kwk/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
}
a {
    float:left;
    height: inherit;
    width: auto;
    background:red;
}
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

**Edit :** or if you want to place image in center of div you can use like this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/71y96kwk/2/)**

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    background:red;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
a {
    max-height:100%;
    width: auto;
}
img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

**Edit :** To remove Extra space use width and height as 100% for `<img>` like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/71y96kwk/4/)**

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 100%;  }
a {
    height: inherit;
    background:red;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    display:inline-block;
}
img {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect, but the <a> became bigger. How to remove the extra space in around the <img> ?

Comment: The first. On the right side I have a navigation and I don't have enough space because of the <a>.

Comment: The extra space is on the right side of the image (red). http://jsfiddle.net/71y96kwk/3/

Comment: I think it's enough to remove the float:left; from <a>. Width 100% height/width the image doesn't keep the ratio.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing height of the `#container` from `inherit` to `100%`.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#inner {
    height:100px;
    padding:15px 0;
    background:yellow;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}

a {
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    width: auto;
}

img {
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="inner">
    <div id="container">
        <a href=""><img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```