# How to have a full-width image in a div that has padding?

Tags: html, css, sass

Html:

```
<div class="myDiv">
    <img class="myImage" src="...." >
</div>
```

Css:

```
.myDiv {
    padding: 20px;
}
.myImage {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    // ??
}
```

I don't mind that there will be space above and below the image (20px since the container has that as padding) But width-wise I'd like to break through the padding and have the image 100% of the div. Is this possible?

Comment: `padding:20px 0;` ?

Comment: You want image height and width to be same as .myDiv

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334028/img-inside-div-with-padding

Answer (score 4):

You can use margin in negetive.

```
.myImage{
  margin-left:-20px;
}
```

**OR**

Do it with position

```
.myDiv {
    padding: 20px;
    position:relative;
}
.myImage {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0; // or 20px as you want
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: A negative margin sorts out the left hand side, but the right hand side now essentially has 40px padding ?

Comment: If you noticed i shared two cases for first one is to just remove the left spacing for that you want set image size to `100%` but second case i completely fine for you,

Answer (score 1):

You have two approachs:

- First one: Add `padding` only in one axis.

```css
.myDiv {
    padding: 20px 0 ;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.myImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background.png" >
</div>
```

- Second one: Use negative `margin`.

```css
.myDiv {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.myImage {
    margin: -20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv">
    <img class="myImage" src="http://www.hdbloggers.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Background.png" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this differently too. Instead of having a full-width image inside a padded div, you can have a padded div inside full-width image (contained by a div).

```css
.full-width-image {
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080') no-repeat center center;
}

.padded-div {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width-image">
  <div class="padded-div">
    I am a padded div with a full-width background.
  </div>
</div>
```